# How are they captured?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass

At the beginning of Glass, Kevin and Dunn are captured by the Clover Society/police. The doctor says something like

> No one needs to get hurt anymore, David.

How did they know where they were, and specifically, Dunn's name?